# how to calculation variables inside a function

Tags: javascript

my problem is that the var total doesn't calculate the variables but concatenat them together but when i use numbers instead of the getAttribute('cost') all is working fine...
any way i can work this around?

i have this code

date:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <lable  for="supervisor " style="font-size: 16px ; text-align: center" class="form-control rounded" >Supervisor </lable>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">  
        <select name="supervisor" id="userslist" style="font-size: 16px ; text-align: center" class="form-control rounded " onchange="calculateCost()">
            <option disabled selected >Please Select Supervisor</option>
                <option  cost="111" cost2="300">John Doe 1 </option>

        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <label for="superextra" style="font-size: 16px ; text-align: center" class="form-control rounded " >Extra Houres</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <input type="number" name="superextra" id="super" min ="0" onchange="calculateCost()" value="0" style="font-size: 16px ; text-align: center" class="form-control rounded "> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <label for="supertotal" style="font-size: 16px ; text-align: center" class="form-control rounded ">Total Sum</label> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <input type="number" name="supertotal" id="totalsum" value=""  style="font-size: 16px ; text-align: center" class="form-control rounded ">
    </div>
</div>
```

and the script

```js
function calculateCost()
{

 //  check first that a user has been selected and also date has been picked

if(document.getElementById('userslist').value && document.getElementById("dateforgame").value)  
{ 

  //Supervisor
  let timeZone = new Date().toString().match(/([A-Z]+[\+-][0-9]+)/)[1];
  let chosenDate = new Date(document.getElementById("dateforgame").value + timeZone);
  var obj = document.getElementById('userslist');
  if (chosenDate.getDay() === 6) { 
    var userobj = document.getElementById('userslist');
var selectedUserCost2 = userobj.options[userobj.selectedIndex].getAttribute('cost2');  
   
    
    var extrah = document.getElementById('super').value;
     var extra = 240;
    var total = selectedUserCost2 + (extra * extrah);
    document.getElementById('totalsum').value = total;
    
  } else {
      var userobj = document.getElementById('userslist');
var selectedUserCost = userobj.options[userobj.selectedIndex].getAttribute('cost');
 
  
 var extrah = document.getElementById('super').value;
   var extra = 120;
    var total = selectedUserCost + (extra * extrah);
    document.getElementById('totalsum').value = total;
  }
}

}
```

Comment: try parseInt() or parseFloat(). If you "add" strings together in JS they get concatenated. So it should be `var total = parseInt(var1)+parseInt(var2);`

Comment: Very much agree with @SteveKirsch, parseInt and parseFloat should work. Use as per your need

Comment: As a side note, I'm pretty sure you don't need to parse the date to get the time zone and add it back to create a new date. Maybe have a look at `getTimezoneOffset`

Answer (score 0):

`getAttribute()` method return value type is `String` see [API doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

You need to convert `String` type to `Number` using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)  method in order to 
perform any arithmetic operation.